# Cauchy Integral Formula on region

Tags: complex-analysis

I have an integral problem which seems to me could be solved with Cauchy integral formula. But I wondering about formula hypothesis satisfied.

I have statement for Cauchy's formula:

Let $U$ be an open subset of the complex plane $\mathbf{C}$, and suppose the closed disk $D$ defined as
$$
D=\left\{z:\left|z-z_{0}\right| \leq r\right\}
$$
is completely contained in $U$. Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ be a holomorphic function, and let $\gamma$ be the circle, oriented counterclockwise, forming the boundary of $D$. Then for every $a$ in the interior of $D$,
$$
f(a)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \mathrm{~d} z
$$

**My question**

$$\int_{|z|<1} \frac{e^{i \pi z}}{2 z^{2}-5 z+2} d z$$

**My attempt**

\begin{align*}
\int_{|z|<1} \frac{e^{i \pi z}}{2 z^{2}-5 z+2} d z &= 
\int_{|z|<1} \frac{e^{i \pi z}}{(2z-1)(z-2)} d z \\
&=
\int_{|z|<1} \frac{\frac{e^{i \pi z}}{2(z-2)}}{z-\frac{1}{2}} d z \\
&= 2 \pi i \left[\frac{e^{i \pi z}}{2(z-2)}\right]_{z=1/2}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3} 
\end{align*}

My attempt uses Cauchy integral formula given above. But I corcern can I use that.

If I can not, How can I solve this integral?

Comment: You have computed the integral over the circle $\{|z|=1\}$, not the integral over the region $\{z: |z| <1\}$. Integral over the region $\{z: |z| <1\}$ does not even exist.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{|z|=1}$ ? If so, you can use the Cauchy's integral formula since $e^{i\pi z}/(z-2)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{2\}$.

Comment: Actually my book asks integral on region $\{z: |z|<1\}$ but since I can not figure out that I computed over the circle $z: |z|=1$. I asked this question to know if there is any theorem or conclusion the integral over circle $|z|=1$ and region $|z|<1$ can be equal?